# How can i copy image across region in azure along with the data disk?

Tags: azure, image

I need a solution to copy image along with the data disk or attach a data disk to the existing managed image.

I tried copying the image using az copy but it doesn't copy attached data disk.

Comment: I tried copying the image using az copy and that was successful but it doesn't copy the attached data disk.

Comment: could you please include that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried copying the image using az copy and that was successful, but it doesn't copy the attached data disk.

To copy the disk across region, make use of below PowerShell script

```c
$sourceRG = <sourceResourceGroupHere>
$sourceDiskName = <sourceDiskNameHere>
$targetDiskName = <targetDiskNameHere>
$targetRG = <targetResourceGroupHere>
$targetLocate = <yourTargetLocationHere>
$targetVmGeneration = "V1" # either V1 or V2
#Expected value for OS is either "Windows" or "Linux"
$targetOS = <yourOSTypeHere>

$sourceDisk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $sourceRG -DiskName $sourceDiskName

# Adding the sizeInBytes with the 512 offset, and the -Upload flag
$targetDiskconfig = New-AzDiskConfig -SkuName 'Standard_LRS' -osType $targetOS -UploadSizeInBytes $($sourceDisk.DiskSizeBytes+512) -Location $targetLocate -CreateOption 'Upload' -HyperVGeneration $targetVmGeneration

$targetDisk = New-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $targetRG -DiskName $targetDiskName -Disk $targetDiskconfig

$sourceDiskSas = Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $sourceRG -DiskName $sourceDiskName -DurationInSecond 86400 -Access 'Read'

$targetDiskSas = Grant-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $targetRG -DiskName $targetDiskName -DurationInSecond 86400 -Access 'Write'

azcopy copy $sourceDiskSas.AccessSAS $targetDiskSas.AccessSAS --blob-type PageBlob

Revoke-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $sourceRG -DiskName $sourceDiskName

Revoke-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $targetRG -DiskName $targetDiskName
```

Output:

[image]

To confirm in portal disk copy to another region successfully like below:

[image]

***References***:

[Upload a VHD to Azure or copy a disk across regions - Azure PowerShell - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-upload-vhd-to-managed-disk-powershell)

[Attach a data disk to a Windows VM in Azure by using PowerShell - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-disk-ps)

Comment: But I also want to attach it to the image. How do I achieve that?

Comment: This tells how to attach the disk with the VM, not the image. I want this disk attached to every VM created using the image.

Answer (score 0):

I created a VM using my image and then followed the above steps to copy the data disk and attach it to the VM.
Then I took the snapshot of the VM in order to create the image which fulfilled my requirement.